# Empty Cell Causes Code to Break in For Loop - Generating a Google Doc from a Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have been using a script to take information generated by a Google Form that is put into a spreadsheet and put it into a Google doc every time a form submits. The problem I have is, that the code stops at the first empty cell in a row using `break`.  I tried using `continue` but that just places the next cell of data in the array.  Is there a way to put in a place holder like N/A into the array and keep the loop going until a specific cell so that the array matches how many titles there are in the Google doc so that the right information goes with the correct header?

```
  function getRowAsArray(sheet, row) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 99);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var columns = [];

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    Logger.log("Got row", row);

    for(var l=0; l<17; l++) {
        var col = row[l];
        // First empty column interrupts
        if(!col) {
          break;
        }


    }
    columns.push(col);
  }

  return columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code:

```
function triggerFunc() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('My Sheet Name');

  getRowAsArray(sheet, 1);
};

function getRowAsArray(sheet, row) {

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 99);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var columns = [];

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    Logger.log("Got row: " + row);

    for(var l=0; l<17; l++) {
      var col = row[l];
      // First empty column interrupts
      if(!col) {
        columns.push("na");
      } else {
        columns.push(col);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log('columns: ' + columns);
  return columns;
}
```